# Page Cant be Displayed IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I've been trying to troubleshoot but with no success. I'm working on standing a asp.net web site up using vs2013. The solution has one project which is the website. The site builds but when I try and run it I get the dreaded "page can't be displayed" error. I noticed that iisexpress is running in the tasks tray and site is supposedly being served via http://localhost:xxxx but that isn't actually happening.

I removed the site node in the applicationhost.config, closed and reopened the solution with the website. After doing that I still continue to get the "page can't be displayed" error. The url bindings in the applicationhost.config match the what is showing in iisexpress so I'm really lost. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express is not starting the project under the **https** URL. Try changing the default project URL.

open below path

"Web Project->Properties->Web->Project URL" to the URL with https.